# Silverlight OOB-Application - set backgroundcolor of main window to transparent

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I create a Silverlight OOB application in which I try to change the background color of the window transparent. I would like to use as wallpaper its own image. This is not square and therefore interferes with the white background color of the main window.
In the OutOfBrowserSettings I can put as the "Window Style" to "none ".

In WPF there are the two following window properties:
AllowsTransparency = "True"
Background = "Transparent"

Unfortunately, this does not seem to know about Silverlight, though! Does anyone know how I get the background color of the main window transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set beackground to ***{x:Null}***? Or maybe to set the alpha in color to 0 which means transparent. For example **#00FFFFFF** or **#00000000**.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the current version (4) of Silverlight.